# How to completely erase/delete a catkin workspace?

Tags: ros, catkin

I created a catkin workspace (catkin_ws) as required for ROS (robot operating system). I want to delete/erase the entire workspace since I will be removing ROS. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

catkin workspace is not linked to any other places, just delete your `catkin_ws` directory, also if you have added it `~/.bashrc` you can remove it as follows:

1. Open bashrc from any editor

   `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. Remove entries similar to follows:

   `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`

   `source ~/catkin_workspace/devel/setup.bash`

I hope you already remove ROS packages, if it not clear let us know, I will update answer for that as well